# Dynamically updating dependent variables

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

Have just found a gaping hole in my cs knowledge... this code is written in VBA but I'd be really interested to know how to do this in javascript as well !

Basically I'm in a situation where a whole set of variables depends on one variable - something like this :

```
Sub test()
    Dim start As Integer
    Dim var1 As Integer
    Dim var2 As Integer
    Dim var3 As Integer

    var1 = start + 1
    var2 = start + 2
    var3 = start + 3
End Sub
```

My problem is that I want the values of var1, var2 and var3 to update *dynamically* based on the value of start, for example

```
Sub test()
    Dim start As Integer
    Dim var1 As Integer
    Dim var2 As Integer
    Dim var3 As Integer

    start = 0
    var1 = start + 1
    var2 = start + 2
    var3 = start + 3

    ' would like to have var1 = 1, var2 = 2, var3 = 3
    MsgBox "start = " & start & vbNewLine & _
        "var1 = " & var1 & vbNewLine & _
        "var2 = " & var2 & vbNewLine & _
        "var3 = " & var3

    start = 5

    ' would now like to have var1 = 6, var2 = 7, var3 = 8
    MsgBox "start = " & start & vbNewLine & _
        "var1 = " & var1 & vbNewLine & _
        "var2 = " & var2 & vbNewLine & _
        "var3 = " & var3
End Sub
```

But clearly this is not working, I get the same values

```
var1 = 1, var2 = 2, var3 = 3
```

both times. Is there a way to make this work in VBA ? 
And is there a name for this kind of thing so I can better google it ? Something like "dynamic dependent variables" ? Many thanks !

Comment: It's not clear *why* you'd want a set of variables like that. If there's a fixed relationship between `var1` and `var2` then what purpose does `var2` serve ? If you *really* want to do this then you could make your variables properties of a class where only `var1` has a "let" method, and `var2`,`var3` return values based on the internal value of `var1`.

Comment: What you are looking for, I think, is closures. Closures are not implemented in `VBA`, but they are in `VB 9.0`: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2007/05/02/closures-in-vb-part-1.aspx. 
I wouldn't use closures in `VBA`, the language is not designed to do so. The answer below does what you want though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are looking for something like Excel cell formulas and the way they cascade updates.  There is no built-in mechanism for coding like that in VBA.  There are some programming languages that use a paradigm called [Functional Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) that behave in a similar way by chaining functions together and evaluating in a lazy manner, but VBA is more of a (weakly) object oriented, imperative flavor.

One way to solve this type of issue generally is by creating a class to encapsulate all your calculations and using member variables as the base elements of the calculations which would be set first, like `start`, and functions for the derivative numbers, like `var1`, `var2`, `var3`.

Here is an example.  Create a class called `clsRectangle` and copy the following:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public length As Integer
Public width As Integer

Public Property Get diagonal() As Double
    diagonal = VBA.Sqr((length ^ 2) + (width ^ 2))
End Property

Public Property Get area() As Integer
    area = length * width
End Property

Public Property Get perimeter() As Integer
    perimeter = 2 * (length + width)
End Property
```

Next create a module called `mdlMain` and add the following:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim rect As clsRectangle
    Set rect = New clsRectangle

    With rect
        .length = 3
        .width = 5

        MsgBox "perimeter: " & .perimeter & vbCrLf & _
               "diagonal: " & .diagonal & vbCrLf & _
               "area: " & .area & vbCrLf

        'After changing the underlying numbers (like *start* in your example)
        'area, perimeter and diagonal all return new values
        .length = 2
        .width = 7

        MsgBox "perimeter: " & .perimeter & vbCrLf & _
               "diagonal: " & .diagonal & vbCrLf & _
               "area: " & .area & vbCrLf
    End With
End Sub
```

Building a class at compile-time to handle formulaic calculations is good practice because it exposes your math and logic in a very maintainable way and benefits from the syntax and type-checking of the language.  However, it does lack some of the flexibility of a run-time system. If you want to attempt something like that, I can give you some pointers, but it would be a pretty heavy lift to accomplish.  I've done something similar in the past and had to implement [Topological Sort] to figure out what order to perform the calculation updates in based on a graph of prerequisites.

---

I can't speak to Javascript directly as I don't have too much experience with it.  However, Javascript is a much more dynamic language than VBA and it's entirely possible that libraries already exist to do what you want.

Comment: you're right, and this is what i've decided to do. In javascript this kind of thing exists in the Underscore js library, among other places i'm sure. Thanks for a helpful and well-explained answer !

Answer (score 0):

as far as I'm aware this won't be possible in VBA. You could declare your variables at module level (outside of your procedure) and have them updating through a called function as outlined below. It's not quite as simple as you were perhaps expecting, but it is better than manually updating your variables every time 'start' changes.

```
Dim start As Integer
Dim var1 As Integer
Dim var2 As Integer
Dim var3 As Integer

Sub test()

    start = 0
    var1 = start + 1
    var2 = start + 2
    var3 = start + 3

    ' would like to have var1 = 1, var2 = 2, var3 = 3
    MsgBox "start = " & start & vbNewLine & _
        "var1 = " & var1 & vbNewLine & _
        "var2 = " & var2 & vbNewLine & _
        "var3 = " & var3

    start = ChangeStart(5)

    ' would now like to have var1 = 6, var2 = 7, var3 = 8
    MsgBox "start = " & start & vbNewLine & _
        "var1 = " & var1 & vbNewLine & _
        "var2 = " & var2 & vbNewLine & _
        "var3 = " & var3
End Sub

Public Function ChangeStart(StartValue As Long)

start = StartValue
var1 = start + 1
var2 = start + 2
var3 = start + 3

End Function
```